# How to decrease the size of a float-python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a readable file name generator given the number of bytes, but also doing it without if statements or loops:

```
def memory_size(n):
     suffix = ['B','KB','MB','GB','TB']
     return ('%.1f'+suffix[int(math.log10(n)/3)]) %(n/?)
```

I am stumped as to what i can divide 'n' by so that it will show the user the decreased file size without using an if statement or a loop?

Comment: What's so wrong about loops?

Comment: its part of the assignment

Comment: You get the number of decimal digits using the log10() call. You get the divisor using the 10**digits, possibly rounding to whole multiples of three. BTW: The suffix for thousands should be a lower-case k.

Comment: so what would that look like ulrich?

Comment: Nah, I'm not telling. You didn't do any research before asking for clarification here. Stop being lazy!

Comment: would it look like n/(10**log10(n))?

Comment: i was trying alot of different combinations

Comment: possible duplicate of [If/else alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792989/if-else-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

```
1024**(math.log10(n)/3)
```

The stupid thing about not using for loops is you're gonna get annoying float division errors

```
>>> mem(1000000)
'1.0MB'
>>> mem(1000000000)
'0.9GB'
```

I'd put a call to `round()` in your code

Comment: im getting the same answer for 1000 bytes and 10000 bytes they both say 1.0 kb

Comment: I think that is called debugging. If this is an assingment you really should be doing your own work.

Comment: G is a prefix for 1000**3. The one for 1024**3 is Gi.